# How to share data in breezeJS

Tags: breeze, durandal

So here's the case i got a product table and a category table, product has a category, now i want to retrieve partial products meaning only select productId, productName and categoryId
then i also retrieve partial Categorys selecting only the categoryName, so far i tried maping the data.results to breeze entitys for both the category results and the product results but how to share data between them?

For example i want to be able to do this:

```
<section data-bind="foreach: Product">
    <article data-bind="text: productName"></article>
    <article data-bind="text: category().categoryName"></article>
</section>
```

**The mapping logic**

```
function mapDtosToEntities(manager, dtos, entityName, keyName, extendWith) {

    return dtos.map(dtoToEntityMapper);

    function dtoToEntityMapper(dto) {
        var keyValue = dto[keyName];
        var entity = manager.getEntityByKey(entityName, keyValue);
        if (!entity) {
            // We don't have it, so create it as a partial
            extendWith = $.extend({ }, extendWith || defaultExtension);
            extendWith[keyName] = keyValue;
            entity = manager.createEntity(entityName, extendWith);
        }
        mapToEntity(entity, dto);
        entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
        return entity;
    }

    function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
        // entity is an object with observables
        // dto is from json
        for (var prop in dto) {
            if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                entity[prop](dto[prop]);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that i got 2 views one that display products and one that displays categories, in the products view i need some category info and i don't want to hit the server twice to get the same data for both views i want to be able to share that data between them.

Note: I am working with durandal don't know if that would matter.

Comment: Assuming you're already correctly defining the relationship between Product and Category, if you assign category.categoryId = product.categoryId, you should be able to navigate to category by calling product.category. If that doesn't work, perhaps you can show how you're defining the relationship between Product and Category.

Comment: It worked i thought i need something more than that mapping but actually breeze is smart enough to figure the relation out i think it's the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

> **For future reference if any one got the same problem the following**
>   **sample will help you.**

In this sample i am using northwind as a real example on how to accomplish this.

**javascript**

```
var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery,
        manager = configureBreezeManager();

var defaultExtension = { IsPartial: true };

function configureBreezeManager() {
        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('api/northwind');
        mgr.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Category', function () { this.IsPartial = false; });
        mgr.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Product', function () { this.IsPartial = false; });
        return mgr;
}

var model = function(){
  this.Products = ko.observableArray([]);
};

var modelInstance = new model();

function mapDtosToEntities(mgr, dtos, entityName, keyName, extendWith) {
  return dtos.map(dtoToEntityMapper);
  function dtoToEntityMapper(dto) {
    var keyValue = dto[keyName];
    var entity = mgr.getEntityByKey(entityName, keyValue);
    if (!entity) {
      // We don't have it, so create it as a partial
      extendWith = $.extend({ }, extendWith || defaultExtension);
      alert(JSON.stringify(extendWith))
      extendWith[keyName] = keyValue;
      alert(JSON.stringify(extendWith));
      entity = mgr.createEntity(entityName, extendWith);
    }
    mapToEntity(entity, dto);
    entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
    return entity;
  }

  function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
    for (var prop in dto) {
      if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        entity[prop](dto[prop]);
      }
    }
    return entity;
  }
}

var query = new EntityQuery()
    .from("Products")
    .select("productID, productName, categoryID");

var queryx = new EntityQuery()
    .select("categoryID, categoryName")
    .from("Categories");

manager.executeQuery(queryx)
  .then(querySucceededx)
  .fail(function(error){ alert(error + "queryx"); });

function querySucceeded(data) {
  var list = mapDtosToEntities(manager, data.results, "Product", "productID");
  modelInstance.Products(list);
}

function querySucceededx(data) {
  var list = mapDtosToEntities(manager, data.results, "Category", "categoryID");
  manager.executeQuery(query)
  .then(querySucceeded)
  .fail(function(error){ alert(error + "query"); });
}

ko.applyBindings(modelInstance);
```

**html**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Products">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: productID"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: productName"></span> ---
    <span data-bind="text: category().categoryName"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Mapping will work on id matching breeze is smart enough to figure out the relationship and share the data with the product entity.

Comment: Also this code will serve you well if you want to test it on http://learn.breezejs.com/ it will work since they also use northwind :).